# CiviCRM Webform - Dedupe issue when using a shared address

Tags: webform-civicrm, duplicate-contacts

We use webforms to register adults and children for events and memberships within the organisation. We require that adults register with an e-mail address but for children we do not expect this.

We have been testing more advanced dedupe rules (first name and last name and post code) to make sure that when children are registered for events they are allocated to their original contact record in CiviCRM. For better user experience we want to only have the address inputted once.

For some reason when the child entry uses a shared address from the parent the dedupe functionality does not seem to work. This seems to have been a historic issue that which was fixed (https://www.drupal.org/node/1368534) and quickly reviewing the code the logic seems to be there.

Can someone help and let me know if this is something I am missing on the set-up or a genuine bug.

If it is a bug how do we go about submitting for this module?

Answer (score 3):

[Here is the commit](https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm/commit/2228af20a91ed0ef2f85f6629c467ed0257d48c7) originally made to fix that issue. I suggest you check the current version of the code to ensure that function is still working - seems possible that it may have been inadvertently broken during some restructuring around the way contact ids are stored.